# How to read json file in TypeScript (intern 4)?

Tags: typescript, pageobjects, intern

I'm trying to read data from json file in my UI automation project. I'n using [intern 4](https://theintern.io) for this.
I have implemented Page Object Model on my project and i m trying to pass data using json file. I tried the solution from other similar question but doesn't seems to work. My code set up is as follows:

```
loginpage.ts

import {AdvalentBasePage} from "../BasePage";
import {DashboardPage} from "../dashboard/DashboardPage";
import * as LoginPageLocator from './LoginPageLocator.json'
export class LoginPage extends BasePage {
remote: any;
locator: any;
constructor(remote: any) {
    super(remote, LoginPageLocator);
}
getPageTitleText(): string {
    return "Login Page";
}
getPageTitleXpath(): string {
    return this.locator.PageTitleXpath;
}
enterUsername(username: string) {
    return this.remote.findByXpath(this.locator.userName).type(username);
}
enterPassword(password: string) {
    return this.remote.findByXpath(this.locator.passwoed).type(password);
}
async  clickSubmitBtn() {
    var self = this;
    await self.remote.findByXpath(self.locator.loginBtn).sleep(5000)
        .click().end().sleep(5000);
    var dashBoard: DashboardPage = new DashboardPage(self.remote);
    return Promise.resolve(dashBoard);
}
}
```

but its giving error as follows:

```
  src/pages/login/LoginPage.ts(3,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module './LoginPageLocator.json'.
```

Can some one please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a typings file for a `*.json` declaration. For example you can create a file like `json-loader.d.ts`:

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

You shouldn't need to do anything special with this file ... as long as it's picked up by `tsc` you should be able to import `.json` files as you're attempting to do.

Source: https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79

Comment: i have already created this file.  but should i include this file somewhere ? because just creating didn't make any change.. and i have refered same article .

Comment: Are you sure it's being picked up by `tsc`? Maybe there is something excluding it from your pattern

Comment: even json-loader.d.ts is not being picked up by tsc

Comment: @CodeBloded how are you compiling TypeScript?